# PsychoPy 1.90.1 won't launch on Ubuntu 16.04 (ImportError: No module named requests.exceptions)

Tags: python-3.x, psychopy

I am new to using Linux (using Ubuntu 16.04) and I'd like to program an experiment using PsychoPy. I've installed PsychoPy using the command sudo apt-get install psychopy which worked, but when I am trying to run it, it just won't launch (neither via the menu board nor using the command psychopy %F - ImportError: No module named requests.exceptions).

Very much appreciate any kind of help with this very basic problem, thanks!

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem and I post my solution below:

You can try to use the [NeuroDebian](http://neuro.debian.net/) repository for downloading PsychoPy.

Simply follow these steps:

1. `wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/xenial.de-md.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list`
2. `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install psychopy`

This will add NeuroDebian to your personal package archives (PPA) and then download psychopy from there.

Comment: "The neurodebian (apt-get) installation is no longer up to date or supported - to [install on linux](https://www.psychopy.org/download.html#linux-install) right now you need to use conda or pip". [Source](https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/issues/1791)